# arctext.js to work with inputed text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a generator and I am using the arctext.js plugin. (http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/)

Here is my problem. I have an input field where people can type any text they want. After that there are sliders for font-size, letter spacing, and text arc.

the arctext.js works great on text that is there when the page loads, but not on text inputed.
Here is my code for the text that is input

```
/* top */
$(document).on('keyup', '#bead-top-text', function(e) {

    $('#bTop').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'));

});
$(document).on('change', '#bead-top-font', function(e) {

    $('#bTop').css({'font-family': ''+$(this).val()+'', 'font-weight': 'normal'});

});
$("#bead-top-font-size").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 28,
  min: 10,
  max: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#bTop').css({'font-size': ui.value+'px'});
  }
});
$("#bead-top-letter-spacing").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#bTop').css({'letter-spacing': ui.value+'px'});
  }
});
$("#bead-top-arc").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {

    $('#bTop').arctext('set', {
                    radius      : ui.value, 
                    dir         : 1, 
                    animation   : {
                        speed   : 300
                    }
                });
  }
});
```

I am at a loss. Any ideas on how I can get this working? The generator is at http://www.xbracelets.com/xgen/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using the solution Erik posted here: [Why does the changed input field change the element but no longer allows Jquery arc effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894495/why-does-the-changed-input-field-change-the-element-but-no-longer-allows-jquery)

changed this code from this:`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#bead-top-text', function(e) {

    $('#bTop').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'));

});
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#bead-top-text', function(e) {

    $('#bTop').arctext('destroy');
    $('#bTop').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'));
    $('#bTop').arctext({radius: 1100});

});
```